# MediaMetadataRetriever in Android 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android

I want to use MediaMetadataRetriever to show cover of URL music.
In Android 2.2, I try below code, it works, but not in Android 2.3.3.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(url);
byte[] cover_array = mmr.extractAlbumArt();
cover = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cover_array, 0, cover_array.length);
```

In Android 2.3.3, I try below code, it works, but not in Android 2.2.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(url);
byte[] cover_array = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
cover = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cover_array, 0, cover_array.length);
```

getEmbeddedPicture() will compile fail in Android 2.2.
extractAlbumArt() will compile fail in Android 2.3.3.
I want to fix in Android 2.2 and 2.3.3 at the same time.
How canI do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can't use it in 2.2 because `MediaMetadataRetriever` class is since from api level 10 (working in 2.3.3 or above )

***See here:***

[image]

[**Further for more Detail**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Answer (score 4):

In spite of the docs, it actually does work fine in 2.2, based on my own testing and what I've read online.

From what I've read it actually worked in older versions of Android as well, it just wasn't documented.

I don't know why the Android docs say it was added in API Level 10 (Gingerbread MR1)...I suspect that may be when it was added to the docs?

Comment: @lorne and nLL: how do i import MediaMetadataRetriever in a project which i am compiling on OS 2.2?

Comment: import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the OS [build version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) at runtime and use a simple if/then to decided which method to call?