# How to see the tittle/artist of a radio audio that is being played with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, mediastore, internet-radio

I made a program that connects to a radio and plays its audio using MediaPlayer. I want to print the artist, song title ... but I do not know how.

I tried to do this with MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, the but it didn't work, because I can't "link" the uri with the MediaStore, so when I used this command it searched in my SD target for music.

After that, I tried to do this with MetaMediadataRetriever with:

```
private void play() {
 textView.setText("Conectando con la radio......");
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://streamingraddios.com:9169");
 try {
     if (mp == null) {
         this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
     } else {
         mp.stop();
         mp.reset();
     }

     mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); 
     MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
    // mmr.setDataSource(this, myUri);          
     //String ton= mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
     mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
     mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

     mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
     mp.prepareAsync();

     Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
 } catch (Throwable t) {
     Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
 }

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    textView.setText("");
    textView.setText("Hola: " +ton);
}
```

But the application doesn't respond anymore (without closing the app) when connect with the URI with the variable mediametadataretriever . I think the problem is "context", do anyone know what is it? I don't know how to inicialize this variable. 
Anyone can help me? Thanks you a lot.

Comment: What exactly did you try (any code snippet) that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(myContext, myUri)

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

etc.

needs api 10 though

Comment: This however says it was included in api5 but just not documented http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713652/mediametadataretriever-in-android-2-2-and-2-3

Comment: I have only this class, so my context is "this" (The ActivityMain), it's very rare because when I inicialized my variable MediaPlayer and I used the command mediaplayer.setDataSource(this, myUri) it worked correctly and without errors.

Comment: Yeah if that is the activity then calling this will pass the context. Glad it worked, can you mark as correct

Comment: noo!! Sorry, I explained it wrong. With the MediaPlayer variable the command mediaplayer.setDatasource(this, myuri) works correctly, but with my MediaMetaDataRetriever variable the command mediametadataretriever.setDataSource(this, myuri) doesn't work... (and I don't know how to solve this). Do you want me to paste all the code of my ActivityMain?